# Mongo Aggregation How to match an array inside lookup without using $expr

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline query (I've removed unnecesary stuff) that work when using $expr but doesn't work without. However, I want to avoid using the $expr for better performance, so the indices will be used. Logically there is a many to many relation here between rule and resource. I want to summarize the cost of the resources per rule. The problem here is to match the resources inside the grouped array without using an expression.

with $expr:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
{'$group': {'_id': {'rule_id': '$rule_id'}, 'rule_id': {'$first': '$rule_id'}, 'resources_ids': {'$push': '$resource_id'}}}, 
{'$lookup': 
    {'from': 'other_collection', 
     'let': {'resources_ids': '$resources_ids'}, 
         'pipeline': [
             {'$match': 
                 {'$expr":
                     {'$and': [
                         {'$in':['$resource_id', '$$resources_ids']}
                     ]}
                 }
             }, 
             {'$group': {'_id': {}, 'total_cost': {'$sum': '$cost'}}}], 'as': 'results'}}])
```

without $expr:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
{'$group': {'_id': {'rule_id': '$rule_id'}, 'rule_id': {'$first': '$rule_id'}, 'resources_ids': {'$push': '$resource_id'}}}, 
{'$lookup': 
    {'from': 'cost_data', 
     'let': {'resources_ids': '$resources_ids'}, 
         'pipeline': [
             {'$match': 
                 {'$and': [
                      {'resource_id': {'$in': '$$resources_ids'}}, 
                  ]}
             }, 
             {'$group': {'_id': {}, 'total_cost': {'$sum': '$cost'}}}], 'as': 'results'}}])
```

Comment: Rather than using `"$match"` in the `"$lookup"` `"pipeline"`, how about using [`"localField"` and `"foreignField"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array)?

Comment: No, `$expr` is a must if you want to use `$match` stage in a lookup pipeline. [Reading](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-let)

Comment: I need the match for more conditions. The cost is not per resource but per rule. It is a M2M relation here as mentioned.

Comment: $expr is not required inside the match. I've done this already. However, here because of the array I am building through the pipeline it doesn't let me use it in the match without an $expr.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@rickhg12hs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130282/mongo-aggregation-how-to-match-an-array-inside-lookup-without-using-expr#comment130883230_74130282) gives the right answer. There shouldn't be any need for `$expr` here. The `localField`/`foreignField` syntax will work correctly when the `localField` is an array without needing to `$unwind` (or use `$expr`) as [documented here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array). Therefore the matching component of your `$lookup` can effectively look like this:

```
    $lookup: {
      from: "foreign",
      localField: "resources_ids",
      foreignField: "resource_id",
      as: "result"
    }
```

You can compare the outputs of [this syntax above](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y6Rg5DmJByG) with the [more verbose `pipeline`/`$expr` version](https://mongoplayground.net/p/urQNLjw8QCK) to see that they are the same.

A few other thoughts come to mind. The first is that you can combine the `localField`/`foreignField` syntax with the `pipeline` syntax so that the second `$group` can still be nested inside of the `$lookup`. This would make the final version of the `$lookup` stage structured as follows:

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "foreign",
      localField: "resources_ids",
      foreignField: "resource_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {},
            "total_cost": {
              "$sum": "$cost"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "result"
    }
  }
```

Playground demonstration of that component is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xjxjdT8GK3G).

The second thing is that using an index to perform the `$lookup`s is important and will likely improve performance, but it may not make this operation "fast". As written, this aggregation will perform a full collection scan to process all of the documents in the source collection. (You will still see that `COLLSCAN` in the `explain` output from this source collection even if the index in the other collection is used for the `$lookup`).

Finally, the index on the other collection should probably be `{ resource_id: 1, cost: 1 }`. This should allow the database to [cover the query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) when doing the `$lookup`s and avoid fetching those documents altogether.

---

Edit to address [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130282/mongo-aggregation-how-to-match-an-array-inside-lookup-without-using-expr/74140467#comment130900801_74130282):

> $expr is not required inside the match. I've done this already. However, here because of the array I am building through the pipeline it doesn't let me use it in the match without an $expr.

This is not correct. Specifically the source of the array isn't relevant here. Whether the array is a field in the source document directly or generated in an earlier pipeline stage doesn't matter to the `$lookup` stage at all. In fact, it won't even know where that array comes from, just that it is a field in the generated document that is passed to it.

Rather, what you are describing is the behavior of `$match` itself. From [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

> `$match` takes a document that specifies the query conditions. The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax; i.e. `$match` does not accept raw aggregation expressions. Instead, use a `$expr` query expression to include aggregation expression in `$match`.

Said another way, you presently cannot reference *any* fields from the document (regardless of where they come from or what type and value they have) without `$expr`.

But that fact should mostly be irrelevant for your use case. You can use the `localField`/`foreignField` syntax for this array matching. If you need to match on additional filters then you can *also* leverage the `let`/`pipeline` syntax in the same `$lookup`. [Here is an arbitrary demonstration of that](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fseWDadDl3P) (note the `_id: 4` document doesn't match due to the mismatched `otherVal`).

It is also worth noting that `$expr` itself does not preclude the usage of indexes in general. One current exception, unfortunately, seems to be with `$in` ([reference](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549)). Again though, that shouldn't matter for you if you place that part of the `$lookup` matching into the `localField`/`foreignField` parameters.

Comment: I need the match for more conditions.
The cost is not per resource but per rule. It is a M2M relation here as mentioned.

Comment: In the playground. your local has an array, however I have to build this array at real time from the first collection.

Comment: _Where_ the array comes from, whether directly in the source document or computed in a stage before the `$lookup`, doesn't matter. The `$looukp` stage itself is just going to use whatever it finds in that field name when it goes to execute it. Regarding the first comment, can you update the comment with some examples of the additional conditions to match on? You can certainly further combine the `localField`/`foreignField` syntax with the full `let`/`pipeline` syntax (my example above shows most of that, just without the `let` and additional `$match`).

Comment: I've appended to my answer to address some additional concerns around `$expr` and additional matching

Comment: Every raw in the first collection has only one resource. I am grouping them at the first step by using push, before the lookup. The other matches I'm doing are filters on the second collection like date ranges and others that might apply... anyway matching is not something I can skip.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you avoid doing the matching. Rather, I'm asking for additional information about your use case and remaining concerns so that we can make sure that this answer addresses it completely. Can you help clarify (perhaps with example data) what part of your question and desired behavior isn't handled with the answer so far?